# insert extension into files without extension by htaccess

Tags: php, linux, windows, .htaccess, pdf

I have several files without extension for example:

```
NAME 1
NAME 2
```

They are not extension, bit I would like to insert extension .PDF  using htaccess.

When accessing the url

```
localhost / NAME1
```

even without extension through htaccess recognize .pdf extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the question such that your actual files in the server side file system *do* have file name extensions ("/path/to/xxx.pdf"), but that this extension is missing in the requested URLs. If that assumption is corrrect (your question is vage...), then this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /$1.pdf [END]
```

Here it is important that you do not simply copy and paste that snippet, but that you actually *understand* what is coded there, so that you can adapt it to your specific needs. The excellent documentation of the rewriting module is a good help in that: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: It worked but I have a list of 20 file names, instead of using RewriteRule ^ /? (. +) $ /$1.pdf [END], how can I do it?